# How to add custom colors to Bulma?

Tags: sass, bulma

I have found this code:

```
$custom-colors: null !default

$colors: mergeColorMaps(("white": ($white, $black), "black": ($black, $white), "light": ($light, $light-invert), "dark": ($dark, $dark-invert), "primary": ($primary, $primary-invert, $primary-light, $primary-dark), "link": ($link, $link-invert, $link-light, $link-dark), "info": ($info, $info-invert, $info-light, $info-dark), "success": ($success, $success-invert, $success-light, $success-dark), "warning": ($warning, $warning-invert, $warning-light, $warning-dark), "danger": ($danger, $danger-invert, $danger-light, $danger-dark)), $custom-colors) !default
```

How to extend the list of colors and classes associated with each color?
It's clear I need to define a variable `$custom-colors` before including Bulma, but it's not clear what format of $custom-colors should be? I didn't find an example or good description of that. Any help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found this, I test it and works perfectly. You must add this to your customized sass main file.

https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/2244

https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/

```
$orange: #ff8606;
$orange-invert: findColorInvert($orange);
$custom-colors: ("orange": ($orange, $orange-invert));
```

After this, you can use the new color like:

```html
<button class="button is-orange">Orange</button>
```